# Get nid of nodes which contains FPP

Tags: 7, panels

I have some fieldable panel pane and I can attach this FPP in diferent nodes with panelizer functionality.

How can I get nid of nodes which contains(attach) this FPP programmatically ?

I have fpid but how can I check in which nodes use this FPP ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a similar solution, I work on a site with thousands of fieldable panel panes and need to find all the nodes that contain a certain fpid. The most promising lead I've found is: [Find node programmatically by field value](https://www.drupal.org/node/1895532) so if you've found a better solution (maybe using views) I'd like to hear about it.